# Error Installing iPhone App on Device

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-id

I set up all my certificates and keys today and am trying to run my project on my iPhone.
I'm encountering this strange error:

> Your mobile device has encountered an unexpected error (0xE800003A) during the install phase: Verifying application

Poking around the Apple Developer forums, I've attempted to set new certificates and provisioning profiles as well as editing `Info.plist`, but no matter what I do I can't seem to run the app on my device.

The only think I can currently think of is that my project name in Xcode differs slightly from my development provisioning profile (it uses a question mark), but I've named it according to Apple's conventions: `com.mycompany.myapp`, so I'm unsure if that's the problem.

Any ideas?

**Edit: I've hard restarted the phone, rebooted Xcode, cleaed my targets, set up a new wildcard App ID and respective provisioning profile and still nothing. Any other ideas?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that I had 2 certs in keychain that were simultaneously overwriting each other! I hope this helps people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a wildcard app ID; com.mycompany.*. That may help.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this on many occasions.  What i do is clean all targets, shut down xcode, and hard reboot my phone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different error than the more common problem of getting the cert wrong...

Restore the phone (using the XCode Organizer to reload the latest OS), to be safe do not restore from backup when you sync with iTunes the first time (it'll still keep your number when you sync even if you don't use the backup).  I've had to do this a very few times, the last one was when it was in the middle of deployment when I unhooked the phone from the cable (had to answer a call).

Try the reboot (of the phone) first, hooking it up with XCode off.  But if that does not solve things, restore is the way.

Answer (score 1):

The console tab in the XCode Organizer sometimes gives helpful hints as to what happens during the install phase. In one case my problem was my app already existing on the phone. I deleted my app and the install succeeded.

Regardless, it looks like a lot of error messages are bundled into this one cryptic message and to really diagnose what is going on, I found the Console tab very useful...

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to try is reinstalling the iPhone SDK. I ran into an error like this when I first got my developer key and this was the only way around.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say to everyone, when you go to edit Targets-> be sure to set "configuration" in the top left corner to "All Configurations" or the correct config you are building for (Debug or Release). You might think you have things set correctly but it will be for the wrong configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error on a correctly provisioned device that has had success installing apps from XCode before, and I've had luck restarting the **device** and trying again. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try running in Release mode instead of Debug. I have a working project with this problem. No idea what the issue was, but running it in Release mode works, but Debug mode produces the error code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a support ticket open with Apple dev support for the same problem, and (FWIW) I'll post their recommendations if and when they can get my toolchain working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (source: http://ephemera.lifewithalacrity.com/iphone_development/)

Even though this is supposedly only for Distribution builds, it helped me to be able to install my Debug version on my iPhone again, after it mysteriously broke yesterday.

"just triple check that all the code signing in your project properties are clear or default"

Note, this is the PROJECT properties as opposed to the TARGET properties. I set my Code Signing Provisioning Profile back to the default and removed the Code Signing Identity string.